# Sparql query returned value integer, cant filter it to get the int

Tags: xsd, integer, sparql, dbpedia

Although the query returns the country names without filter the population, while i use the filter to take the integer returns nothing.

```
PREFIX  dbo:  <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT DISTINCT  str(?country_label) ?population
WHERE
  { 
?country  dct:subject  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Countries_in_Europe>.
?country rdfs:label ?country_label.
?country dbo:populationTotal ?population.
FILTER langMatches( lang(?country_label), "EN" )
FILTER datatype((?population) = xsd:integer ) 

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with this FILTER condition, but the reason your query returns zero results is that none of the population values are of datatype `xsd:integer`.

As an aside there is something else wrong in your query: using a function like `str()` in your SELECT clause without binding the result of that function to a new variable (using `as ?new_var`) is not legal SPARQL. I know the DBPedia endpoint allows it, but you should be aware it's likely to give you errors if you ever try it on a different SPARQL engine.

If you run the query without the datatype filter:

```
PREFIX  dbo:  <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT DISTINCT  (str(?country_label) as ?cl) ?population
WHERE
  { 
?country  dct:subject  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Countries_in_Europe>.
?country rdfs:label ?country_label.
?country dbo:populationTotal ?population.
FILTER langMatches( lang(?country_label), "EN" )

}
```

You will see that the [result](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX%20%20dbo%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20DISTINCT%20%20str%28%3Fcountry_label%29%20%3Fpopulation%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20%0D%0A%3Fcountry%20%20dct%3Asubject%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FCategory%3ACountries_in_Europe%3E.%0D%0A%3Fcountry%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fcountry_label.%0D%0A%3Fcountry%20dbo%3ApopulationTotal%20%3Fpopulation.%0D%0AFILTER%20langMatches%28%20lang%28%3Fcountry_label%29%2C%20%22EN%22%20%29%0D%0A%20%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20) contains only values of datatype `xsd:nonNegativeInteger`. That's a *different* datatype, and although it is of course true that every non negative integer is also an integer, datatype inference  of this form is not something that most SPARQL endpoint support.

Also: in your original filter condition on population, you have the parentheses placed wrong. If you modify your query as follows:

```
PREFIX  dbo:  <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT DISTINCT  (str(?country_label) as ?cl) ?population
WHERE
  { 
?country  dct:subject  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Countries_in_Europe>.
?country rdfs:label ?country_label.
?country dbo:populationTotal ?population.
FILTER langMatches( lang(?country_label), "EN" )
FILTER ( datatype(?population) = xsd:nonNegativeInteger ) 

 }
```

You will get back all values that are of that datatype - though, as said, I'm not sure what you're achieving here, as this is the same result you'd get without the datatype-check, as far as I can tell.

If your goal is to get the number back, but represented as an `xsd:integer` instead of as a `xsd:nonNegativeInteger`, you can of course cast it, instead:

```
PREFIX  dbo:  <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT DISTINCT  (str(?country_label) as ?cl) (xsd:integer(?population) as ?pop)
WHERE
  { 
?country  dct:subject  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Countries_in_Europe>.
?country rdfs:label ?country_label.
?country dbo:populationTotal ?population.
FILTER langMatches( lang(?country_label), "EN" )
 }
```

Comment: Thank you. it worked this way, i wanted the population number and couldnt understand this xsd:nonNegativeInteger

Comment: @NikosSimaiwhat is the purpose if this FILTER at all? I mean, `dbo` namespace are mapping based DBpedia properties, so they should all be numbers.